# Using fancybox AND a css hover effect - conflict

Tags: jquery, css, hover, fancybox

I had a simple css hover effect which works fine however I also needed to add a fancybox gallery to this same group of images but even though fancybox works ok, the hover effect doesn't.

the hover effect uses this css:

```
.hov-eft:hover > div {
opacity: 0.3;
-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
}

.hov-eft:hover > div:hover {
opacity: 1.0;
transition: all 750ms ease;
-webkit-transition: all 750ms ease;
transform-origin: 50% 0%;
-webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
transform-style: preserve-3d;
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

and I simply add this class to the section and it works however throwing fancybox in, I am struggling.

Here is the rest of my code:

HTML

```
<section class="hov-eft">
<div class="image-container">
                        <a rel="test1" href="#" ><img    src="http://s29.postimg.org/nkhruktyb/image.jpg" style="margin-right:25px;" alt=""/></a>
                        <a rel="test1" href="#" ><img src="http://s29.postimg.org/nkhruktyb/image.jpg" style="margin-right:25px; display:none;" alt="" /></a>
                        <a rel="test1" href="#" ><img src="http://s29.postimg.org/nkhruktyb/image.jpg" style="margin-right:25px; display:none;" alt="" /></a>
                        <a rel="test1" href="#" ><img src="http://s29.postimg.org/nkhruktyb/image.jpg" style="margin-right:25px; display:none;" alt="" /></a>


                        <a rel="test2" href="#" ><img src="http://s29.postimg.org/8r349tm77/image.jpg" style="margin-right:25px;" alt=""/></a>
                        <a rel="test2" href="#" ><img src="http://s29.postimg.org/8r349tm77/image.jpg" style="margin-right:25px; display:none;" alt="" /></a>
                        <a rel="test2" href="#" ><img src="http://s29.postimg.org/8r349tm77/image.jpg" style="margin-right:25px; display:none;" alt="" /></a>
                        <a rel="test2" href="#" ><img src="http://s29.postimg.org/8r349tm77/image.jpg" style="margin-right:25px; display:none;" alt="" /></a>
   </div>
</section>
```

JS

```
$("a[rel=test1]").fancybox();
$("a[rel=test2]").fancybox();
```

[JSFIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/9GzfD/)

Can anyone advise how I can get the 2 working together?

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
.hov-eft  div:hover a{
   opacity: 0.3;
   -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
}

.hov-eft  div a:hover {
   opacity: 1.0;
   transition: all 750ms ease;
   -webkit-transition: all 750ms ease;
   transform-origin: 50% 0%;
   -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
   transform-style: preserve-3d;
   -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Pesulap/9GzfD/2/)